# Route all the requests to specific database express node js

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, mysql-connector

I am working on a saas app (separate db for each client) backend uisng node js, express and mysql and sequelize orm.
Url is : http://example.com/customer/api
Here customers count can be in 1000's
Now i need to get that customer name and connect to there database and then route all the requests to that database.
When ever a request comes this has to be done.
// first connect to the customer db
Then
app.use('/api', routes)
routes here has all the routes on the application.
What is to be done to handle this? I need a way to connect to that customer db as and when requests arrive and then process requests on that customer database.

Comment: assuming you have implemented authentication, store client's database information in your app's database. when request comes in based on client's auth token find fetch client's database info and connect to that database dynamically. Perform what every query was sent and close the connection.
FYI: since request is made over http there is no way to persist database connection for client's next consecutive queries unless you switch to websocket.

Comment: Understood. I am connecting to the db using sequelize and storing that connection in a variable and that variable is sent to req.db = connection. This is in one middleware after this I call next(). Which will go to app.use('/api', routes). My question is does the routes here know which db to connect?

Comment: yes it will, since middleware runs on every request,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you get the corresponding database?
a middleware could route between the different databases for example user "x" makes a request. The middleware searches for the corresponding database for user x and puts the connection String for the database in the req.
The handler for the request than gets the conn String and connects to the corresponding database. The connection could than be cached with for example `node-cache` and than retrieved later on when the customer needs another request.

**Edit:**

some code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
    
var getDb = function (req, res, next) {
  req.body.username //get for example the username
  //search for the corresponding connection string in the database
  //then add it to the request
  req.databaseString = connString //connString --the connection 
  // String you got earlier
  next();
};
    
app.use(getDb);
    
app.get('/makeSomething', function (req, res) {
  //connect to db with req.databaseString
  //do what you wanna do
    
  res.send('done');
});
    
app.listen(3000);
```

Adding to your comment above.
"My question is does the routes here know which DB to connect?"
the routes know this when they look in the `req` and look for a connection string. With the connection String they know which DB to use.

Comment: Can you add in some dummy code and elaborate?

Comment: Does it me that what ever db connection is specified in the req, the req gets executed in that database itself? Without any further changes @stingscreen

Comment: Could you maybe share some code? @Sathvik Bhandar

Comment: Current project URL:
http://localhost:3000/api/{allRoutes}
Everything works till now after adding in the new URL format it does not work

I want to take the customer name from the URL for example
http://localhost:3000/TestCustomer/api/{allRoutes}
var getDb = function (req, res, next) {
       const client = req.url.split('/');
       const customer = client[1];
      req.db = connString of customer;
      next();
    };
    
    app.use(getDb); //Work fine till here

app.use('/api', routes); // Here fails due to adding of customer name

Comment: Can I do like app.use('/customer') and then app.use('/api', routes)